# Number of connected components of a real variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

Let $f_1,\ldots,f_k\in\mathbb{R}[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$ with $d_i:=\deg f_i$ and suppose that $V:=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\,:\, f_1(x)=f_2(x)=\ldots=f_k(x)=0\}$ is of dimension $n-k$. I would like to bound the number of connected components. If $k=n$ then by Bezout a bound is $d_1\cdots d_n$. Does this bound generalize to $k<n$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be careful when applying Bezout's theorem as you have (even the higher dimensional version). That bound works (as stated in the theorem) when the intersection is a collection of finite points.

Havings said that, there are some further generalizations which you might find useful. In Fulton's book on intersection theory (volume 2), it is mentioned that if we have affine varieties (in general schemes) $X_1,...,X_r$ in $\mathbb{P}^n$ whose codimensions add to at most $n$, then

$$\sum deg(Y_i) \leq \prod deg(X_j)$$

where the $Y_i$ are the components of the intersection of the $X_j$. You can read more about this here:

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/42127/generalization-of-bezouts-theorem

If you want a better bound, then the question is more difficult. You can read about one such result here:

http://arxiv.org/pdf/0806.4077.pdf